# Magic Mouse Lag

Tags: bluetooth, mouse

I have a magic mouse (I tried 2 different mouses) and I have experienced lag during use.

I tried to remove plist, `sudo pkill bluetooth`, turn off and turn on.

- Ventura 13.2.1
- Magic Mouse 1.9.2
- MacBook Pro 15-inch, 2017

**UPDATE**
I'm trying another monitor with a display port (direct to my mac), and it seems ok. The previous monitor is with HDMI and I use a non-Apple adapter.

Comment: Could you precise what kind of "lag" you are encountering?

Comment: the pointer is not fluid during the movement, it seems that it has a "resistance"

Comment: Which Mac model do you use? Can you try with a different BT mouse and see whether the same happens? And with a wired model?

Comment: I tried two different mouse (two Magic mouse)

Comment: I encountered a problem very similar to yours. In my case the refresh rate of the display was set to 30 Hz and mouse was lagging a lot. As soon as set it to 60 Hz everything was fine again. I don't have any idea why it was set to 30 Hz, but few days ago macOS did reset the "resolution" of my external monitor to the default 1920x1080. Maybe a cable glitch too.

Answer (score 0):

You can try resetting your mac’s NVRAM.

1. Shut down your mac
2. Turn on again
3. Hold <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>
4. Let it reset 2-3 times without releasing keys
5. Release and let it reboot normally
6. Reconnect your mouse

Normally, this should resolve your problem for the laggy Magic Mouse.

**If not working**, try disconnecting and reconnecting your mouse.

Comment: I did it before create the post

Comment: Have you tried the disconnect/reconnect?

Comment: It's the first thing that I did before changing the monitor, removing Plist, resetting Pram, try another mouse, change Resolution Screen.

Comment: Uhhh..no.  First, it’s NVRAM. PRAM was used with PowerPC (PowerBook, iMac G3/G4, etc) and when Apple switched to Intel processors, it changed to NVRAM.  Second, ***there’s nothing in NVRAM that will effect Bluetooth in macOS***.  The only BT entries are for the EFI boot.  Dump the nvram contents with the command `nvram -xp` and you’ll see there is nothing that will change BT behavior in macOS.

Answer (score 0):

When Bluetooth lags, it’s usually due to some sort of radio interference (basically all wireless is boiled down to simple radio waves).  Think of it when you have a poor connection to a wireless headset and the sound cuts in and out - that the same as your mouse “lagging.”

- Try pairing your mouse with another device like an iPad away from your main computer.  Computer equipment generates EMF radiation that could interrupt radio signals.  This will take your mouse out of the equation so to speak.  If it work fine away from your computer, you know it’s not your mouse and you need to focus your efforts elsewhere
- Take your MacBook away from your desk and pair/use your mouse in this “out of the box” state.  Find a location away from electronic equipment.  If this combination works well in another location, there’s something in or around your desk that’s causing interference.  You’ll need to do some investigation here.

> I'm trying another monitor with a display port (direct to my mac), and it seems ok. The previous monitor is with HDMI…

It really has nothing to do with HDMI vs DisplayPort (DP is better video signaling, IMO), but with the *cable*. Many inexpensive, no-name cables cut costs by using poor quality (or none at all) shielding to prevent rogue EMF from escaping and causing interference.  If this switch fixed your issue, you’ve found the culprit.